# Permission Error When Calling a Function That Takes a Feature Class and Writes Each Row to A csv

Tags: arcpy, convert, permissionerror

When calling this function within the class method export_Tables:

```
     def export_Tables(self):
        ##TODO - Need to Modify This Function To Loop Through Each FC And Export
        def tableToCSV(path, input_tbl, csv_filepath):
            arcpy.env.workspace = path
            fld_names = [fld.name for fld in arcpy.ListFields(input_tbl)]
            
            with open(input_tbl, 'w') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                writer.writerow(fld_names)
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(path, input_tbl), fld_names) as cursor:
                    for row in cursor:
                        writer.writerow(row[0])
                        del cursor
```

with passing the following params:

```
             inFiles = r'C:\Users\mmulford\Desktop\SURE_Moderinization_GeocodeExtracts\Geocode_OutputTest\Outputs.gdb'
        out_csv = r'C:\Users\mmulford\Desktop\SURE_Moderinization_GeocodeExtracts\CSV_ReadyToFormat'
        arcpy.env.workspace = inFiles
        XY_address = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for addressTable in XY_address:
            tableToCSV(inFiles, addressTable, out_csv)
            print(addressTable)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1154, in ListFields
    return gp.listFields(dataset, wild_card, field_type)

  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 354, in listFields
    self._gp.ListFields(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))

RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.'
```

For clarification, the Feature Classes when passed to the function are point vectors of geocoded addresses.

I am unsure what is causing this issue, and everything I have tried with changing/modifying my path names hasn't worked.

Any thoughts?

EDITS: Updated Code portions and resulting error message.

Comment: Shouldn't `inFIles` on line `tableToCSV(inFiles, out_csv)` be `addressTable`?

Comment: Do you have the CSV file open in another application? And its hard to tell from your fragment, but is `csv_filepath` from `with open(csv_filepath, 'wb') as csv_file:` an actual file, or is it the dir?

Comment: I have updated the code above to reflect some of these comments.

The intent of this portion is to write each row to a csv. The csv will be created at the moment it begins writing.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your call to ListFields--try breaking that piece out and simplifying.  Try using a hard-coded string to specify the input data set using the full system path to the data in the call to the function and make sure it's working. Sometimes the tools are weird in the way they do or don't use the env.workspace variable--you might need the full system path and not just the table name.

Comment: I ended up just brute forcing it and using arcpy.conversion_TableToTable. It outputs a csv and an xml, so I just looped through the directory and deleted any files with the extension of '.xml'